# what is excel VBA combobox change event?

Tags: excel, vba, events, combobox

I am writing a VBA code in my excel.  I have combox box in my worksheet in excel.
I want to run specific sub-routine when different item in the comboxbox is selected by user.

Is there any event when the combobox is updated ?

Thank you for help in advance

Comment: Are you using ActiveX or Forms combobox control?

Comment: I used Forms combobox control.

Answer (score 1):

- Go into the code module for your sheet.
- Select your combobox from the objects dropdown.
- Change is the default event but if you needed another event the available events are in the other drop down to the right.

[image]