# Vba: SOLVING COMBOBOX

Tags: vba

Basically I have two combobox in my userform using vba language. My problem is I want to display data automatically in combobox2 based on user selection in combobox 1. Any suggestion for vba language?

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Student() As Variant
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Student = Selection
Me.ComboBox1.List = Student
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you got some source code you can post here?

Comment: Did you try the Change event as mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090182/what-is-excel-vba-combobox-change-event

Comment: @kobusSmit..I already try it and you can see my code above.

Comment: @NewUser Your code above just fill the `ComboBox1` with the choices, no less no more. See my answer for more information on how to fill `ComboBox2` regarding the value of `ComboBox1`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the basics for that kind of linked choices :

Your code, without the useless (and greedy) `.select`, with a better way to get last used row and assigning range to an array with `.Value` :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim Student() As Variant
    Student = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    Me.ComboBox1.List = Student
End Sub
```

And there is the part that you'll need to work on :

**When you change the value of the** `ComboBox1`, it'll launch that code, so you need to **refresh in there the values proposed in** `ComboBox2` with your own tests, as we have no clue of what you are doing.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim RestrictedChoices()
Me.ComboBox2.Clear 'Clear all previously added elements
Me.ComboBox2.Value=vbNullString 'Set active value as an empty string

'------Here is where you need to do your tests-------
'if Me.ComboBox1.Value<> ?? then
'Else
    Me.ComboBox2.AddItem "Array filled or item, after test on Me.ComboBox1.Value"
'End If

End Sub
```