# Changing view to relevant cells after event change in dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

I'm extremely new to VBA and I don't find the answers and tutorials to be very informative.

So what I want to do is to detect whether the value selected in the dropdown list has changed, and from there on change the view of the excel sheet to the relevant cells.

My problem is that a lot of the sample VBA codes don't really come with explanations. Right now what I have is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    'SWITCH CASE CODE HERE

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

But tbh I don't really know what `EnableEvents`, `ScreenUpdating`, `Calculation` do.

I want to know

1. how exactly to detect event change in a drop down box and get the value of the drop down box (I'm still thinking in Java here)
2. how to switch view to selected cells

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Updated code which still isn't working...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Prints nothing
Debug.Print Target.Address

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

    'Prints nothing
    Debug.Print Target.Value

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    If Target.Value = "Goto B1" Then
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = B
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You need  `Worksheet_Change` not `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. 
If the dv list is in a1 then target will be a1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found the solution to the problem.

Suppose the dropdown selection box is at cell A1,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    If Target.Value = "Goto B1" Then
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2 'Column B
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    End If

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two kind of comboboxes you may use in a Spreadsheet; one is a form element and the other you may create by using **Data Validation** / **List** option.

If the combo is formed by **Data Validation** then your code would work even though I do not have the chance of trying at the moment.

If your combo is a form element, then you may refer to this answer: [Combobox Change Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090182/what-is-excel-vba-combobox-change-event)

I do not exactly get what you need by "Switch view" but if you want to locate to another cell from the code, you may use a `Range("A1").Select` type code.

Also you may use to **Record Macro** feature of Excel; play around and see what code Excel creates for your actions inside Excel. Then you may use these code portions in your actual code as a kind of reference.

Comment: By "changing the view", I mean switching the current range of cells viewable to the range of cells I want.

A normal Excel file starts at A1. Switching the view basically means automatically scrolling to the cells I want to see.

Comment: This is basically selecting a cell, so the `Range("A1").Select` code will work for this purpose.

Comment: I've replace the code within the if-then clause above with `Range("A1").Select`. The cell is selected, but the view is not changing. I still have to scroll.

Comment: Change `A1` with the actual cell reference you want to activate, that's just an example.

Comment: Yeah, that's didn't work. As I mentioned, the cell is selected, but if I'm looking at A400 right now, the screen does not scroll back up to the selected cell. It has to be done manually. I've found my solution though.